# maven + jetty but el expression not work fine

Tags: el, maven-jetty-plugin

I use maven + jetty plugin (6.1.26) , in jsp page , I write ${title_name} work fine . but if i write ${title_name == null? "default name" : title_name} , it throw Exception like this :
            org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/layout/header.jsp(13,9) PWC6038: "${header_title==null?"defaultName":header_title }" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: ${header_title==null?"defaultName":header_title }
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.validateExpressions(JspUtil.java:649)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:752)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:946)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2341)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:498)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2341)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:541)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$IncludeDirective.accept(Node.java:647)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2341)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:498)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1853)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:210)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:435)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)

but all of the expression above is worked fine in tomcat , what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Jetty changed during its versions EL parsers, version 6.X should use glassfish or jboss EL parse...
since version 9 they moved to apache EL parsers.

Possible solutions:

Add apache jasper & el jars to project (Bad workaround)
Move to jetty 9 and everything should work fine!